# resize image, add watermark then save

Tags: php

i read some topics similar to this but couldn't understand
i just want to upload images resize them then add watermark and finally save
this is my code :

```
     $targetDir = "picem/"; 
     $watermarkImagePath = 'icon/stamp.png'; 


if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){ 
    // File upload path
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $name => $value)  
  {  
    $fileName = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name'][$name]); 
    $new_name = md5(rand()) . '.' . $fileName[1];
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $new_name; 
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 


    // Allow certain file formats 
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg'); 
    if(in_array($fileName[1], $allowTypes)){ 
        // Upload file to the server


        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$name], $targetFilePath)){ 
            // Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to 
            $watermarkImg = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkImagePath); 
            switch($fileType){ 
                case 'jpg': 
                    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath); 
                    break; 
                case 'jpeg': 
                    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath); 
                    break; 
                case 'png': 
                    $im = imagecreatefrompng($targetFilePath); 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath); 
            } 

            // Set the margins for the watermark 
            $marge_right = 10; 
            $marge_bottom = 10; 

            // Get the height/width of the watermark image 
            $sx = imagesx($watermarkImg); 
            $sy = imagesy($watermarkImg); 

            // Copy the watermark image onto our photo using the margin offsets and  
            // the photo width to calculate the positioning of the watermark. 
            imagecopy($im, $watermarkImg, (imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right)/2, (imagesy($im) - $sy 
             - $marge_bottom)/2, 0, 0, imagesx($watermarkImg), imagesy($watermarkImg)); 

            // Save image and free memory 
            imagepng($im, $targetFilePath); 
            imagedestroy($im);
```

i would really appreciate if someone help me to make the result of
                 imagepng($im, $targetFilePath);
small image because right now i get some files with the size of 10MB

Comment: PNG files are lossless and will be large for large dimensions. A JPEG source will often be far smaller, so I'd suggest JPEG in, JPEG out.

Comment: Don't forget you can let a case "fall through" if two inputs have the same code. Do `case 'jpg':` and right after on the next line `case 'jpeg':` followed by the code and `break`.

Comment: Why not control the size of your file upload at entry? Set a limit to the file size and validate on entry.

Comment: i tried more solutions but nothing